# Jest test (ReferenceError: google is not defined) ReactJS and Google Charts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme, google-visualization, jestjs

[image]

I'm using the google script tag from their CDN (tried body and head)
`<script src="https://wikitags.com/js/googlecharts.min.js"></script>`

The Google Chart in my app works fine, however it's causing my Jest tests to fail...

---

Inside of the `<ChartComponent />`

```
componentDidMount() {
    // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
    console.log('Chart mounted');
    google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['corechart', 'line'] });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(this.getSocialData({ days: this.state.days }));
}
```

Is there a simple way around this?

---

### What I've tried

```
import React from 'react'
import { mount, shallow } from 'enzyme'
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json'
import Trends from './Trends'
import Chart from '../entity/Chart'
const body = { subject: { id: 0 } };
const TrendComponent = shallow(<Trends body={body}/>);
const func = function() {};
let google = {};

const setGoogleObj = () => {
    google = {
        charts: {
            load: func
        }
    }
}

beforeEach(() => {
    return setGoogleObj();
});

const TrendComponentMount = mount(<Trends body={body} google={google}/>);

describe('<Trends />', () => {
    it('renders', () => {
        const tree = toJson(TrendComponent);
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot(TrendComponent);
    });

    it('contains the Chart component', () => {
        expect(TrendComponent.find(Chart).length).toBe(1);
    });
});
```

Comment: Is "google" an import or a global variable ?

Comment: Sorry, it's a script tag import from their CDN, was in the body, but I also tried putting it in the head

Comment: In that case use beforeEach() hook of Jest and assign a dummy object to variable google. I suggest sinon.js for mocking / stubing it's behaviour and don't forget to clean up after you're done.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, looking at the Docs now, tried setting a dummy object, but unsure how to pass it in? It's not a prop

Comment: Just declare it as a global : globals.google = {} or google = {}

Comment: @Burimi I get globals is undefined in my test when I try that, I added my full test file above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147183/discussion-between-burimi-and-leon-gaban).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Had to add this to my `jest` key inside of package.json

Thanks to [@Burimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/497255/burimi) for helping me debug, this setups a default global

```
"jest": {
  "globals":{
    "google": {
    }
  }
  ...
```