# How can I test google.maps.Geocoder?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, testing, jestjs

> Hi! I'm attempting to write a "simple" test to check for a react class component state change. Specifically, I'm testing if the lat(latitude) and lng(longitude) states change if Google successfully geocodes some string(address) that I send it. Here is an example of what I want to test `(i.e. the lat and lng states being set to results[0].geometry.location.lat())`:

```
getLatLong = (address) => {
    const that = this;
    var geo = new google.maps.Geocoder;

    geo.geocode({'address':address},(results, status) => {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            that.setState(
            {
                center: {
                    lat: results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
                    lng: results[0].geometry.location.lng(),
                },
            });
        }
    });
}
```

In my jest suite, I'm having issues writing my test and spying/mocking out the google.maps.Geocoder because the google library is never imported. It is attached via a script, like so:

```
<script async defer
    src=<%="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=#{Rails.application.config.google_api_key}&callback=initMap"%>>
</script>
```

> Just so its confirmed, the code works as intended after manual testing, but I receive errors inside my testing suite when attempting to spy like so:

```
let geocoderSpy = jest.spyOn(google.maps, 'Geocoder');
```

> I receive an error like this:

```
  ● EventMap › getLatLong works as intended by getting coordinates of valid locations › calls the geocoder function

ReferenceError: google is not defined

  34 |         let geocoder;
  35 |         beforeEach(() => {
> 36 |             let geocoderSpy = jest.spyOn(google.maps, 'Geocoder');
     |                                          ^
  37 |             geocoder = jest.createSpy('Geocoder', ['geocode']);
  38 |             geocoderSpy.and.returnValue(geocoder);
  39 |         });

  at Object.google (app/javascript/__tests__/EventPage/EventMap.test.jsx:36:42)
```

So then, I followed up this problem and found this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44660338/5356423) and this answer that claimed to solve it by adding something like this to jest in the package.json file...

```
"globals": { "google": { } }
```

This also failed to solve my problem. **I think the solution is to somehow find out how to import google, but not quite sure how to do that....** If anyone can help me out that would be greatly appreciated. I would love to learn how to test something like this. In advance, many thanks. Austin

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that you are not the only one having suffered through the terrors of testing Google maps with Jest. I found a lot of projects and conversations around. But they all seem to recommend mocking the Google maps library, by doing something similar to this :

```
const setupGoogleMock = () => {
  /*** Mock Google Maps JavaScript API ***/
  const google = {
    maps: {
      places: {
        AutocompleteService: () => {},
        PlacesServiceStatus: {
          INVALID_REQUEST: 'INVALID_REQUEST',
          NOT_FOUND: 'NOT_FOUND',
          OK: 'OK',
          OVER_QUERY_LIMIT: 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT',
          REQUEST_DENIED: 'REQUEST_DENIED',
          UNKNOWN_ERROR: 'UNKNOWN_ERROR',
          ZERO_RESULTS: 'ZERO_RESULTS',
        },
      },
      Geocoder: () => {},
      GeocoderStatus: {
        ERROR: 'ERROR',
        INVALID_REQUEST: 'INVALID_REQUEST',
        OK: 'OK',
        OVER_QUERY_LIMIT: 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT',
        REQUEST_DENIED: 'REQUEST_DENIED',
        UNKNOWN_ERROR: 'UNKNOWN_ERROR',
        ZERO_RESULTS: 'ZERO_RESULTS',
      },
    },
  };
  global.window.google = google;
};

// in test file.
beforeAll(() => {
  setupGoogleMock();
});
```

(source : https://github.com/hibiken/react-places-autocomplete/issues/189#issuecomment-377770674)

There is even an npm package for it! https://github.com/hupe1980/jest-google-maps-mock

Not sure if it will solve your problem, though, because this will only allow you to check **if you have correctly called the right method** from the API, not to check **if you get the correct response** from the API.

However, I don't know if it is advisable to actually do real API calls when testing such a functionality.

Comment: Thank you! This helps quite a bit. I figured I had to do something along these lines just didn't know where to start.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. To adapt your solution to my project I had to refactor the Geocoder - function into a class. I will post my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the answer from Mathieu. I had to make a little change to adapt this solution for my project (Nuxt.js/Vue.JS).

I've replaced the Geocoder function with a mock of the Geocoder class.

```js
const setupGoogleMock = () => {
  /** * Mock Google Maps JavaScript API ***/
  const google = {
    maps: {
      places: {
        AutocompleteService: () => {},
        PlacesServiceStatus: {
          INVALID_REQUEST: 'INVALID_REQUEST',
          NOT_FOUND: 'NOT_FOUND',
          OK: 'OK',
          OVER_QUERY_LIMIT: 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT',
          REQUEST_DENIED: 'REQUEST_DENIED',
          UNKNOWN_ERROR: 'UNKNOWN_ERROR',
          ZERO_RESULTS: 'ZERO_RESULTS',
        },
      },
      Geocoder: class {
        public async geocode() {
          return Promise.resolve()
        }
      },
      GeocoderStatus: {
        ERROR: 'ERROR',
        INVALID_REQUEST: 'INVALID_REQUEST',
        OK: 'OK',
        OVER_QUERY_LIMIT: 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT',
        REQUEST_DENIED: 'REQUEST_DENIED',
        UNKNOWN_ERROR: 'UNKNOWN_ERROR',
        ZERO_RESULTS: 'ZERO_RESULTS',
      },
    },
  }
  // @ts-ignore
  global.window.google = google
}
setupGoogleMock()
```