# Manually mock Google Maps in Jest

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jestjs

I want to mock the google maps API that I am using with the @googlemaps/js-api-loader package.

For now, I need to ensure that the geocoder was called and I am trying to do so by:

```
const mockGeocoder = jest.fn();

jest.mock('google.maps.Geocoder', () => () => ({
  geocoder: mockGeocoder,
}));
```

But I get

```
Cannot find module 'google.maps.Geocoder' from 'tests/unit/usecases/maps/getPlaceByAddress.spec.ts'

  3 | const mockGeocoder = jest.fn();
  4 |
> 5 | jest.mock('google.maps.Geocoder', () => () => ({
```

Not sure how to proceed. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found it on Stackoverflow. Dont know why yesterday Google didnt recommend this to me.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58439971/how-can-i-test-google-maps-geocoder) is where I found the answer

So I did the following:

```
const setupGoogleMock = () => {
  global.window.google = {
    maps: {
      Geocoder: jest.fn(() => ({
        geocode: mockGeocoder,
      })),
      GeocoderStatus: {
        ERROR: 'ERROR',
        INVALID_REQUEST: 'INVALID_REQUEST',
        OK: 'OK',
        OVER_QUERY_LIMIT: 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT',
        REQUEST_DENIED: 'REQUEST_DENIED',
        UNKNOWN_ERROR: 'UNKNOWN_ERROR',
        ZERO_RESULTS: 'ZERO_RESULTS',
      },
    } as any,
  };
};
```

and then  `beforeAll(() => { setupGoogleMock(); });`

Answer (score 2):

Check the package https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/jest-mocks for mocks and examples. I'm not sure if Geocoder has a mock, but it should be possible to follow the pattern there (and send a pr).