# Mocking in Jest (Typescript - Mock chrome namespace)

Tags: typescript, npm, google-chrome-extension, jestjs, babel-jest

I have a **chrome extension in react**.
I started to add some test, but i am having a hard with some tests.

I want to test my **`<App/>` component**, but i get an error in any way i have tried it.

By doing this:

```
import React from "react";
import { render, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import App from "../../App";
import { BMEUtils } from "../../app/helpers/utils/BMEUtils";
import { FormContainerID } from "../../app/dom-elements/_components/forms/AbsoluteContainer";
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';


describe("tests ", () => {

  it("test App", () => {
    const component = renderer.create(
      <App />,
    );
    const b = document.getElementById(FormContainerID)
    const a =  document.getElementById("login-btn");
    
    let tree = component.toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    
    expect(a).not.toBeNull();
    expect(b).not.toBeNull();
   
  });
});
```

I get a error during the test

```
ReferenceError: chrome is not defined
```

Because one of the components calls this namespace to add a listener (`chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener`)

I have tried:

```
global.chrome = jest.fn() as any;
jest.mock('chrome');
```

```
import chrome from "sinon-chrome";
 beforeAll(function () {
    global.chrome = chrome as any;
 });
```

```
const chrome = require('sinon-chrome/extensions');
beforeAll(function () {
    global.chrome = chrome ;
});
```

```
var globalRef:any =global;
globalRef.chrome = jest.fn().mockImplementation();
const component = renderer.create(
   <App />,
);
```

```
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
const wrapper = mount(
   <App/>
);
const p = wrapper.find('#login-btn');
```

**But none of them worked for me**.

This is my main problem.

Other problem that i have, and may be related to the previous, is that i dont know how to mock the implementation of some functions that are executed inside the method i am calling, and are not modules.

For example

```
// Test as Base64 Image
// Utils is a namespace
test('base64Image', () => {
  ...
  const file = ...;
  let base64Image = Utils.asBase64Image(file);
  expect(base64Image).not.toEqual("");
  ...
});
```

```
function asBase64Image(file:File) {
  ...
  canvas.getContext("2d");
  img.onload
  ...
}
```

The workaround that i came up with is to use Modules to replace those functions and mock them, for example instead of `img.onload` -> `module.loadImage(img).then(...)`
but i want to learn the correct way to do it if it is possible.

Anyway my real problem now is that i can not test my `<App/>` component.

Comment: can you show me the component that you need to add tests? thanks

Comment: You can see the code here, in the typescript box:

https://jsfiddle.net/Doppelgr/yk13u2r9/

The purpose of this component is to be able of calling app functions by using shorcurts and to request data from the current tab.

Comment: Well, actually i started by testing the whiole ```<App/>``` component to make sure that the app has no errors and after this i was going to test each component in specific tests. But testing the ```<App/>``` component gives me this error.

Here is the App component:
https://jsfiddle.net/Doppelgr/m6vwrdgu/1/

(Yes, i know i have a folder-naming issue, i will refactor some code in the future)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still struggling with this in 2023, I solved by the following:

```
import { pathsToModuleNameMapper, type JestConfigWithTsJest } from 'ts-jest';
const chrome = require('sinon-chrome/extensions');

const config: JestConfigWithTsJest = {
  extensionsToTreatAsEsm: ['.ts'],
  verbose: true,
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/default-esm',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts)?$': ['ts-jest', { useESM: true }],
  },
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['./dist'],
  moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths /*, { prefix: '<rootDir>/' } */),
  // setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./jest.setup.js'],
  globals: {
    chrome,
  },
};

export default config;
```

credit to https://stackoverflow.com/a/44660338 for the pointer!